# Do I need to install Update Manager whenever it is displayed?

Tags: 10.04, installation

When I open my computer and want to use Ubuntu 10.04 I find Update Manager every week displayed on my computer asking for installation.

Do I need to install whenever it is being asked, or I can ignore it? How many times in a month do I need to install it?

Answer (score 4):

We can open *"Settings..."* for options on how often Update Manager checks for updates, and to always install security updates in the background.

#### 10.04 LTS

[image]

#### 12.04 LTS

[image]

The automatic check for updates can be set in steps from *Never, Every two weeks, Weekly, Every two days,* and *Daily*.

It is recommended to check for security updates frequently. You may install them automatically in the background without getting a notice. Updating of other packages can be done whenever this is convenient, but you will not get bugs fixed until you do it.

Answer (score 3):

You should install as often as possible in order to keep your system safe and reliable. But you don't have to. And you can run the update manager whenever you feel like it. But you can also have a look at the details. Sometimes it's obvious that the fix doesn't apply to you, in which case it isn't important that you install it.

Answer (score 1):

Every time would be the best. But I don't do that either, only when I see security updates I will update immediately otherwise I update when I have the time to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to distinguish between what is mandatory (what you have to do) and what is recommended (what you should do):

- You don't *have* or *need* to install *any* update. The system should work without being updated.
- It's a wholly different thing what is recommended though. It's recommended to keep your system updated so that it gets security fixes and updates. You'll benefit from this by getting a more secure system (the fixed security issues cannot be exploited) and a more updated system which is hopefully more stable.

If you're bothered by the update manager popping up I suggest you do as [Takkat recommends](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57773/do-i-need-to-install-update-manager-whenever-it-is-displayed/57783#57783) and have Automatic updates set to "Install security updates without confirmation" (Update manager - Settings - Updates - Install security updates without confirmation). With this settings you should be OK to ignore the Update manager most of the time. Do the updates when you have time and feel like it, e.g. do it roughly once a month.

Also note that you can set it to look for updates less often (Update manager - Settings - Updates - Check for updates). This way it won't popup as often.